# Slicing lists for every grouped values... in one line... possible?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with US census data. I wanted to group states with their correspondent counties. There's also another column with population ordered from high to low. I am struggling to "glue" states and counties so they can be sorted by high to low. The other thing I am trying to do is to slice it so I only get the three first most populous counties for each state. I would like to do that code all in one line? Maybe it's asking too much.

This is how the list looks atm:

```
STNAME         CTYNAME                 
California     Los Angeles County          9818605
Illinois       Cook County                 5194675
Texas          Harris County               4092459
Arizona        Maricopa County             3817117
California     San Diego County            3095313
               Orange County               3010232
New York       Kings County                2504700
Florida        Miami-Dade County           2496435
Texas          Dallas County               2368139
New York       Queens County               2230722
California     Riverside County            2189641
               San Bernardino County       2035210
Nevada         Clark County                1951269
...
```

This is the code I wrote:

```
def answer_six():
     return census_df[census_df['SUMLEV'] == 50].sort_values(['CENSUS2010POP'], ascending=False).set_index(['STNAME', 'CTYNAME'])['CENSUS2010POP']
answer_six()
```

This is what I would like to see (I am making up the results):

```
STNAME         CTYNAME                 
California     Los Angeles County          9818605
California     Cook County                 5194675
California     Harris County               4092459

Arizona        Maricopa County             3817117
Arizona        San Diego County            3095313
Arizona        Orange County               3010232

New York       Kings County                2504700
New York       Miami-Dade County           2496435
New York       Dallas County               2368139
```